JavaScript property not properly updated
I am using JS and electron and am really confused. See following code
console.log(s)
console.log(s.canFire)
console.log(s)

produces following output(see image)
Image of output
BUT as you see the first and third console log both say that canFire is 0 but the second console log says it's 1.
Rectangle class
export class Rectangle extends Shape{
  constructor(canvas, x, y, width = 20, height = 50,fillColor = "blue") {
    super(canvas, x, y, fillColor);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.type = "Rectangle"
    this.canFire = 0
  }


Context in which the above code is happening.
I also do not use async code that accesses s in any way.

Whatever's happening this random three-line portion of your code isn't enough to tell us why it's happening.

@AlexanderNenashev It does. Thank you very much. That is indeed quite unexpected behavior
